# I have windows vista and I am the only user. Why do I have an administrator account and user account with my name?

Tags: windows-vista

How can I combine my "Administrator" account and my User ("Desiree") account?  I am the same user and can only do certain things with each account.  For example, if I want to print something-I have to log in to my "Desiree" account, and if I want to download anything I can only do so if I am logged in to my "Administrator" account.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that "Administrator" account is a built-in account. I'm not sure if you could combine them. But you can log in to your Administrator account and change your account (Desiree) to an Admin account Control Panel. That way, your account will have administrator privileges, too.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mess with that account.  The built in Admin account you see is left in there for reasons of backwards compatibility and (to a lesser extent) recovery reasons.

It is normally diabled by default because it had been a common target for malware in the past.  Under XP and earlier, the builtin Admin account was enabled. Since it had the same ID number on every XP installation, it was a sitting target.

However, it(the built in) has no more privileges than any other Admin account. I would create a set of Admin and User accounts for your use and heavily advise you disable the built in Admin account.